# Is there a better way to write this code that inserts an element into a sorted list in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm working on exercise 7 on https://iloveponies.github.io/120-hour-epic-sax-marathon/one-function-to-rule-them-all.html. I've got a solution, but because the expected output is a list, I've had to add a 'reverse' to some of my outputs. This seems a bit hacky.

Here's my code:

```
(defn insert [sorted-seq n]
  (loop [output ()
         my-seq sorted-seq]
    (cond 
     (nil? (first my-seq)) 
       (conj output n)
     (nil? (first (rest my-seq))) 
       (reverse (conj output (first my-seq) n))
     :else
      (if (> (first (rest my-seq)) n (first my-seq))
        (reverse (apply conj output (first my-seq) n (rest my-seq)))
        (recur (conj output (first my-seq)) (rest my-seq))))))

(insert [] 2)      ;=> (2)
(insert [1 3 4] 2) ;=> (1 2 3 4)
(insert [1] 2)     ;=> (1 2)
```

Is there a better way of writing this that will be more efficient, and not require reversing the outputs? Also, the first 2 conditions seem clunky. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the point of the exercise is to work with recursion, not necessarily to produce the most idiomatic code. You can avoid the reversing by using a data structure that does `conj` to the right, a vector.

```
(defn insert [sorted-seq n]
  (loop [s sorted-seq, a []]
    (cond 
      (empty? s)       (conj a n)
      (< (first s) n)  (recur (rest s) (conj a (first s)))
      :else            (apply conj a n s))))
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I skimmed over the rest of the questions and didn't notice the recustion part.

Comment: I used a vector, but then noticed that the output was as a list. I wondered why that might have been - perhaps there was a function I should have used. Maybe there was no reason after all... But thanks. I had too many conditions in mine. Yours is much more concise.

Answer (score 3):

@A.Webb's solution is the one you're looking for, but leaving this for the future visitors.

I think you overcomplicated the problem slightly.

The general idea is this:

1. Find the site where you need to insert the element.
2. Split the sequence in two at that point.
3. Concatenate the first resulting sequence, the element, the second resulting sequence.

You can combine 1 and 2 using [split-with](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/split-with), which splits the sequence in two parts: one where a predicate is true, and the other where it is false.

So, speaking clojure:

```
(defn insert [coll n]
   (let [[l r] (split-with #(< % n) coll)]
       (concat l [n] r))
```

Comment: I'm guessing the comparison to 3 should be n instead?

Comment: @soulcheck We haven't covered split-with, but I'll check it out. It looks handy. Thanks.

Comment: @jbrown yeah that's probably what you'd use if it wasn't an exercise in recursion.

Comment: If this weren't an exercise you wouldn't use a sorted list at all: they're a bad datastructure for the task. A sorted set, or a sorted map used as a multiset, or a heap or something, would all be better choices.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite simply with a list provided you are prepared to employ proper recursion:

```
(defn insert [ss n]
  (if (empty? ss)
    (list n)
    (let [[x & xs] ss]
      (if (< n x)
        (cons n ss)
        (cons x (insert xs n))))))
```

- Wrap the body in a `lazy-seq` if you want it to work on long
  sequences without blowing the stack.
- It's still going to be much slower than [A. Webb's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25668674/1562315).